# How to Dynamically Find the padding value modified when size of textview size is increased

Tags: android, textview

**Code:**

```
int sizeValue=10;
myText.setTextSize(sizeValue);
```

`myText` is a textView

**What I am doing**: I am dynamically modifying the sizeValue value and setting the textSize again

**What I am trying to do**: Whenever I increase the textSize, How can I find out how much padding is increased. `TopPadding`, `BottomPadding`, `LeftPadding`, `RightPadding`

***How to resolve this ?***

I have searched solution for this in stackoverflow. There is no existing question on this

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with this,

```
 int sizeBottom=myText.getTotalPaddingBottom();
 int sizeLeft=myText.getTotalPaddingLeft();
 int sizeRight=myText.getTotalPaddingRight();
 int sizeTop=myText.getTotalPaddingTop();
```

it will return the total padding of Textview.